# How do I do an On Demand Backup for an IBM Cloud database

Tags: elasticsearch, ibm-cloud

I have an Elasticsearch deployment in the IBM Cloud and I want to take regular on-demand backups from it. Is there a way of initiating backups using the command line?

Answer (score 2):

IBM Cloud databases takes regular daily backups of all its databases, but you cannot choose the backup schedule. If you want to create backups more often or on. your chosen schedule, you can use the IBM Cloud CLI `backup-now` command.

You can install the CLI [from here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-install-ibmcloud-cli) and you will need to add the cloud databases plugin with:

```
ibmcloud plugin install cloud-databases
```

Log into the IBM Cloud CLI with:

```
ibmcloud login -sso
```

Follow the on-screen instructions to log in.

You can then list all the database deployments in your account with:

```
ibmcloud cdb ls

#Name                          Location   State
#Databases for PostgreSQL-76   us-south   inactive
#testelastic                   eu-gb      active
#Databases for MySQL-9j        us-south   active
#elastic-target                eu-gb      active
```

To back up one of those databases do:

```
ibmcloud cdb backup-now testelastic

#Key                   Value
#ID                    crn:v1:bluemix:public:databases-for-elasticsearch:eu-gb:a/xyz/abc
#Deployment ID         crn:v1:bluemix:public:databases-for-elasticsearch:eu-gb:a/abc/def::
#Description           Creating an on-demand backup
#Created At            2023-02-01T10:09:12Z
#Status                running
#Progress Percentage   0
                      
#Progress Percentage   50
                      
#Status                completed
#Progress Percentage   100
```

There is more information on backup policies [in this document](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-databases?topic=cloud-databases-dashboard-backups&interface=ui)