# How do I restore an IBM MongoDB database that I have accidentally deleted

Tags: database, mongodb, ibm-cloud, backup

I have an IBM Cloud Databases for MongoDB deployment and I have accidentally deleted some documents. How can I restore the lost data?

Answer (score 2):

The IBM Cloud Databases service takes automatic daily backups of your data and keeps them for 30 days. So you can restore one of those backups to a new database deployment. After that, you can either find your missing documents and put them back into your original database, or you can point your application to the new database and go from there.

You can do this using the IBM CLI. You can install the CLI [from here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-install-ibmcloud-cli) and you will need to add the cloud databases plugin with:

```
ibmcloud plugin install cloud-databases
```

Log into the IBM Cloud CLI with:

```
ibmcloud login -sso
```

Follow the on-screen instructions to log in.

You can then list all the database deployments in your account with:

```
ibmcloud cdb ls

#Name                          Location   State
#Databases for PostgreSQL-76   us-south   inactive
#testelastic                   eu-gb      active
#Databases for MySQL-9j        us-south   active
#mongo-target                eu-gb      active
```

You can then list all the backups for your chosen database:

```
ibmcloud cdb backups mongo-target                                                                                                                                                                            #Id    Type        Status      Created At
#crn:v1:bluemix:public:databases-for-mongodb:eu-gb:a/abc123-d2af4a82620b   scheduled   #completed   2023-02-07T15:58:02Z
#crn:v1:bluemix:public:databases-for-mongodb:eu-gb:a/abc123-110596debb85   scheduled   #completed   2023-02-06T15:58:03Z
#crn:v1:bluemix:public:databases-for-mongodb:eu-gb:a/abc123-18a9b1426b7c   scheduled   #completed   2023-02-05T15:58:02Z
```

Choose your preferred backup to restore and then create a new instance of MongoDB using that restore-id:

```
ibmcloud resource service-instance-create mongo-restore databases-for-mongodb standard eu-gb -p '{"backup_id":"crn:v1:bluemix:public:databases-for-mongodb:eu-gb:a/abc123-d2af4a82620b"}'

#Creating service instance mongo-restore in resource group default of account IBM as bob@aol.com ....
#OK
#Service instance mongo-restore was created.
#                     
#Name:                mongo-restore
#ID:                  crn:v1:bluemix:public:databases-for-mongodb:eu-gb:a/abc345::
#GUID:                a33ee45202bf9
#Location:            eu-gb
#State:               provisioning
#Type:                service_instance
#Sub Type:            Public
#Service Endpoints:   public
#Allow Cleanup:       false
#Locked:              false
#Created at:          2023-02-08T11:45:09Z
#Updated at:          2023-02-08T11:45:11Z
#Last Operation:                
#                     Status    create in progress
#                     Message   Started create instance operation
```

Remember that you can also create [On Demand backups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75308793/how-do-i-do-an-on-demand-backup-for-an-ibm-cloud-database/75308794#75308794) if you want to back up your database more regularly.
More documentation on IBM Cloud Databases for MongoDB [can be found here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-mongodb?topic=databases-for-mongodb-getting-started)